# Padding bottom hack not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, image

I'm currently working on a padding-bottom hack to prevent content reflow and it works perfect on desktop.

I have a div which has something like the following;

`<div style="--imageWidth: 300; --imageHeight: 200;"></div>`

And in CSS;

```
div {
  border: 3px dashed magenta;
  padding-bottom: calc(var(--imageHeight) / var(--imageWidth) * 100%)}
```

But on mobile the image looks like the following, it's scaling and there's a large gap between the image and text below.. See image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOobT.png)

Comment: what do you mean by content reflow ?

Comment: do you mean overflow?

Comment: Nope, 'Reflow' is a term in web design

Comment: Could you share a bit more of your markup, so we can reproduce this?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of what it looks like on desktop, as well as mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the inline style and stick exclusively to CSS styles. You could use media query to set parameters for mobile view, this would allow you to style 2 versions of CSS, one for desktop (your CSS) and one for mobile (the media query in your CSS).

the following code will produce a blue background, but green on mobile.

```
/*CSS*/
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

use this same logic to write specific code for your `<DIV>`. add an id to it and call that in css for your desktop style, then use @media to select that id and modify it on a mobile.

you will be able to test it by resizing your browser. You might also want to look into flexbox, its a life saver for this type of thing and you can write CSS inside and outside of the media query for size specific code.

Hope that answers your question. let us know what you find!